# Android AutoCompleteTextView - How to display a property of my class instead memory address?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've implemented an AutoCompleteTextView with a custom ArrayAdapter. Everything works fine except when i choose an item from list. When i choose the item, it changes the values from AutoCompleteTextView to something like:

```
com.android.tests.entity.MyObject@41a0387
```

I'm not able to override the method toString() so i need to convert it to friendly value in android code.

How can i convert it? Can i choose one item and put a friend value in the text value from AutoCompleteTextView?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PassionHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new InterestHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (PassionHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Passion passion = passions.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(passion.getName());
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Why are you `not able to override the method toString()`?

Comment: You always able to override `toString()` because everything is object.

Comment: Because i don't have the dependency here. It's a third part and i'm trying to avoid to do something like 'public class Banana extends MyObject' just to override toString(). Can i do without override toString()?

Comment: if you do not want to override toString() you have to override ArrayAdapter.getView()

Comment: @blackbelt already did that but this only work to list all results that have been found in autocomplete..the problem is when i choose one from result...

Comment: Can you show how do you manage the item click?

Comment: Fixed...need to override convertResultToString(). Edited with solution. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: override the method `convertResultToString(Object resultValue)`:

```
@Override
public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
    Passio result = (Passion) resultValue;
    return result.getName();
}
```